# Работа кода завершается после его выполнения.Питон

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Изначально эхо бот запускался, но после манипуляции с кодом перестал продолжать работу, и после этого я попытался запустить снова простого бота и он тоже не запускается(код выполняется и завершается сразу).

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

    if __name__=='__main__':
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: У вас явно лишний отступ в последних двух строках кода

Comment: Отступ...
И с этим я возился несколько часов.
Питон прекрасный язык, ни шага в сторону!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас лишние отступы перед if, и в итоге Ваш бот запускаеться при вызове функции echo, которая никогда не вызываеться. В итоге python просто делает все импорты, создаёт переменые и функцию и дальше ничего не видит для выполнения, поэтому и прекращает свою работу. Вот рабочий код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__=='__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```